# Create an NTFS read-only file on Windows which would also be read-only on Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, windows

I have a user who wants to distribute read-only word documents created on Windows across the team. This does not seem to work with the user who runs Linux as it seems to ignore the standard NTFS "read-only" flag set in Windows. Unfortunately Linux sees it as a write-allowed file.

This is how the Windows user sets the read-only restriction:

[image]

Can you suggest a way for the Windows user to create a file which will remain read-only in Linux as well?

Comment: Windows inherited the RAHS attributes from MS-DOS (and NTFS inherited them from FAT); they are at best *hints*; anybody can set and reset them. Word has its own built-in mechanism for preventing document modification -- on the ribbon Review tab find Restrict Editing. I have no idea if whatever application the Linux users use will honor the restrictions.

Comment: How are the files being shared?

Comment: @AlexP read-only is for notification/warning purposes. The users decide themselves what they want to do with this. Hence restricting editing in Word is an overkill

Comment: @ajgringo619 They are shared via a direct webdav map, I'm not sure what system the server has but this is the nextCloud file sharing space.

Comment: @ajgringo619 The server is running Ubuntu 9

Comment: @afora377 Ubuntu 9? Do you mean 9.04 or 9.10? Those are both over 10 years old and no longer receiving critical security updates.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was Debian 9. Apologies for my dyslexia